# emulator resets preferences

Tags: android

I have a weird problem - I hope it's just **another emulator malfunction**.
OFTEN (I still have to understand **when it happens and why**), my SharedPreferences are automatically cleared.
I suspect it does it on every build, even if I just edited a comment.
This behaviour is showing up on an Android 2.2 emulator, which I use for backwards compatibility.
I tested the same app on a physical device running Android 4.0.4 and this doesn't happen.
And yes, I do check against nulls before writing any value to the preferences.

What happens is that if i even **add and then remove a single character** (say, a space or a tab) and then remove it, next time I rerun the activity in the emulator, **all preferences are cleared**!! IS THIS NORMAL?? It's at least SHOCKING...

Comment: There is not enough information here.  I suspect you are doing something specifically wrong (are you using snapshots, or otherwise resetting your emulator between runs).  I don't think this is a problem with the emulator (I have never seen this issue myself during normal emulator usage).

Comment: Well, I'm used to emulators BAD BEHAVIOURS... So I wish this is ANOTHER of those. Since my code seems to be correct. And yes, I use snapshots as usual (don't want to reset it to zero all times, loosing everything not only shared prefs). But I loose preferences also in the same session, not only if I change versionName (not versionCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, guys (OK, I had a bad teacher, so i'm guilty at 50%)...

I was using a WEIRD separator between the values of a "MultiSelectListPreference" (I followed a [tutorial](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-multiselectlistpreference-for-sdk-11/)): I was using a sequence of Unicode characters, like "\0001\0007\00d1\0007\0001".

It turned out that the SharedPreference Manager went mad and cleared all the values!!

So, then I changed the separator to a more COMMONN ASCII character: "#".
And it works just perfect.

Maybe this will help someone else who followed the same tutorial.

Anyway, that tutorial works great, if you, like me, want to support older versions of Android and still need to have Checked ListPreferences!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can help you ;). Go to the AVD Manager and edit your virtual device. You can see that
in the bottom of the edition window are "Emulation Options". In this options you can check "Snapshot" option. It cause that emulator state will be persisted between emulator executions.

Comment: Thank you, but it's NOT the case. All my AVDs have that option checked **by default**. I only uncheck it when, due to some emulators's idiosincracies I'm FORCED to wipe data.